# How to select multiple instances from this table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have this table

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------
|          id         |      sender      |     recipient
|---------------------|------------------|------------------
|          1          |       Luke       |       Josh
|---------------------|------------------|------------------
|          2          |       Josh       |       Luke
|---------------------|------------------|------------------
|          3          |       Phil       |       Sam
|---------------------|------------------|------------------
|          4          |       Sam        |       Phil
|---------------------|------------------|------------------
|          5          |       Sam        |       Luke
|---------------------|------------------|------------------
```

Given a name, I want to select just one instance of each interaction with a different user. For exmaple, given the name 'Luke', I wish to select the rows id=1 and id=5 (or id=2 and id=5).

Comment: Have you tried anything in particular?

Comment: `SELECT
  id, sender, recipient from mysql_test_a
WHERE (sender = 'Luke' or recipient = 'Luke')
GROUP BY if(sender < recipient,
     concat(sender, '-', recipient),
     concat(recipient, '-', sender))`

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which MySQL version you are using so I'll assume a modern one, MySQL 8.x.

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select id, sender, recipient
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(order by recipient) as rn
  from (
    select id, sender, recipient from t
    union
    select id, recipient, sender from t
  ) x
  where sender = 'Luke'
) y
where rn = 1
```